# custom RadioButton selected one at a time for iphone?

Tags: iphone, radio-button, state, selected

I have dynamically created some list of RadioButtons with some values. pro grammatically I changed the button state and changed the image for selected and unselected. but the problem is  i can select the all radioButtons at same time. actually I need to select one at a time. 
when I clicked the next RadioButton, previously selected button state should be changed to non-selected.

Here is my code, I tried with changing image, but ...some problem with my code.

```
   RadioButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
   [RadioButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 20, 20)];
   [RadioButton setCenter:CGPointMake(116.0,p1)];
   [RadioButton setSelected:NO];
   [RadioButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [RadioButton addTarget:self action:@selector(RadioButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [self.scrollView addSubview:RadioButton];




  -(void)RadioButtonTapped:(id)sender
    {


       UIButton *RadioButton1 = (UIButton*)sender ;

      [self radiobuttonAction:RadioButton1];
    }

 -(void)radiobuttonAction:(UIButton *)Button
    {

       if(![Button isSelected])
         {


            [Button setSelected:YES]; 
            [Button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_active.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected]; //not working, button image is not changing 
        } 
     else
        { 
            [Button setSelected:NO]; 
            [Button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_inactive.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }


 }
```

where can I change the image of previously selected button.

thanks in advance

Comment: how about making outlet on button, for example you have 3 button, make 3 outlet, so it can be easy to do your problem.

Comment: but i created the buttons dynamically,

Comment: `RadioButtonTapped`-- in this, are you using this in every button?

Comment: yes, the tapped action will be called  when we pressed any of the radio buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deselect all the buttons when you select one. If you have buttons in your scroll view you can user this code:

```
//Your Method
-(void)RadioButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
  UIButton *RadioButton1 = (UIButton*)sender;
  [self deselectAll];
  [self radiobuttonAction:RadioButton1];      
}

- (void) deselectAll : (UIScrollView *) scrollView{
  NSArray *viewArray = [scrollView subviews];
  for (UIView *v in viewArray){
  if([v isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){
        [((UIButton *)v) setSelected:NO];
  }
 }
}
```

**EDIT:** But if you want to give it real radio button effect (in which one is always selected, and only one is selected) it will be more easy to you. Use following code:

```
 //A globle refButton
  UIButton *refButton = nil;
 //Set image for both state:
[RadioButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[RadioButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

 //make any of above default select: may be the last one and pass that to `refButton`
 refButton = RadioButton;



 //Your Method
-(void)RadioButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
  [refButton setSelected:NO];
  refButton = (UIButton*)sender;
  [refButton setSelected:YES];      
}
```

Comment: but, one more doubt, i hjust nsloged tag value NSLog(@"%d",refButton.tag);, but the tag value displays always 0. since i need the tag value to retrive the correspondant data, how is it possible

Comment: have you added tag values to your buttons when you adding these? If no then do so. Then let me know if problem persist.

Answer (score 0):

Tag the button at the time of creation.
When button tapped, get the buttons through tag. Deselect all buttons. Update current button which you have received as a n argument.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you want to add 5 radio buttons.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
      for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
           UIButton*  RadioButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
           [RadioButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 20, 20)];
           [RadioButton setCenter:CGPointMake(116.0, i * 40)];
           //        [RadioButton setTag:i * 10];
           [RadioButton setSelected:NO];
           [RadioButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unCheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
           [RadioButton addTarget:self action:@selector(RadioButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
           [self.scrollView addSubview:RadioButton];

     }
  }

//do not forget to declared this in your header file
-(void)RadioButtonTapped:(UIButton*)button;
 {
       for (UIButton *btn in self.scrollView.subviews) {
          [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unCheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         }
       [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 }
```

the code above updates the UI, sets the image of all buttons to "uncheck" then changes the image of the last pressed button to "check".

Comment: thankyou for your feedback, it works with rptwsthis solution.

Answer (score -2):

create buttons like this,

```
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
 RadioButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 RadioButton.tag = i*100;
 [RadioButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 20, 20)];
 [RadioButton setCenter:CGPointMake(116.0,p1)];
 [RadioButton setSelected:NO];
 [RadioButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [RadioButton addTarget:self action:@selector(RadioButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 [self.scrollView addSubview:RadioButton];

}
```

add action like this,

```
-(void)radiobuttonAction:(UIButton *)Button
{

   UIButton *Button = (UIButton*)sender;
   for(UIButton * btn in self.scrollview.subViews)
   {
     if(btn.tag == Button.tag)
     {
        if(![Button isSelected])
        {
          [Button setSelected:YES]; 
          [Button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_active.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected]; //not working, button image is not changing 
        } 
        else
        { 
          [Button setSelected:NO]; 
          [Button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_inactive.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
     }
     else
    {
      //do selected or de-selected code for other buttons

    }

}
```

Comment: can you please describe why you changed the tag to RadioButton.tag = i*100; , and what should be the result?

Comment: it works now with rptwsthis solution. thankyou for your feedback